# use and show progress dialog while send data

Tags: android, progressdialog

I'm new on android and I want to show a progress bar whenever user do tap on sndbtn and while sending data to my API and when the app finish to sending the data the progress bar have to dismiss.

I'm not sure how to implement the progress with the code that I have. Please some help?

```
sndbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected()) {

                    Request data = helper.sndData(Integer.parseInt(id));
                    request = new Request(Activity.this, API.POST, data);
                    try {
                        String response = request.execute("url").get();

                        Response response = new Response(response);
                        if (responseListModel.isSuccess()) {

                            Toast.makeText(getApplication(), responseListModel.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                            Intent intent = new Intent(Activity.this, NewActivity.class);
                            startActivity(intent);
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplication(), responseListModel.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "Internet Error.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }
    });
```

Comment: Show dialog below `networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected()` and dismiss it in `responseListModel.isSuccess()`. You will also have to dismiss it in the else statement when it fails.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code :

```
public ProgressDialog dialog;

        public void showDialog() {
            if (dialog == null) {
              dialog = new ProgressDialog(getContext());
            }
            dialog.setMessage("Searching");
            dialog.show();

        }

        public void hideDialog(){
            if (dialog != null && dialog.isShowing()) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        }
```

Use these methods in your code :

```
sndbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected()) {

            showDialog();
            Request data = helper.sndData(Integer.parseInt(id));
            request = new Request(Activity.this, API.POST, data);
            try {
                new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {

                        String response = request.execute("url").get();

                        Activity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {

                                hideDialog();
                                Response response = new Response(response);
                                if (responseListModel.isSuccess()) {

                                    Toast.makeText(getApplication(), responseListModel.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                    Intent intent = new Intent(Activity.this, NewActivity.class);
                                    startActivity(intent);
                                } else {
                                    Toast.makeText(getApplication(), responseListModel.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }).start();

            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "Internet Error.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }
});
```

Comment: thanks for trying to help me but i got this error: Non-static field 'dialog' cannot be referenced from a static context

Comment: remove static from method

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using AsyncTask and show dialog in onPreExecute and close dialog in onPostExecute.

```
/**
 * Check holiday schedule
 */
class CheckHolidayNoteAsync(context: Activity) : AsyncTask<Void, Void, HolidayScheduleInfo>() {

    override fun doInBackground(vararg params: Void?): HolidayScheduleInfo {
        //do network stuff here
        return HolidayScheduleInfo(result)
    }

    override fun onPostExecute(result: HolidayScheduleInfo) {
        //close dialog
    }



    /**
     * Runs on the UI thread before [.doInBackground].
     *
     * @see .onPostExecute
     *
     * @see .doInBackground
     */
    override fun onPreExecute() {
       //show progress dialog
    }
}
```

Comment: just a question, is this java or kotlin?

Comment: @hernyval kotlin

Comment: @hernyval just FYI actually you can call this kotlin class from java just like a java class.